# Scala Swing empty space in BoxPanel

Tags: scala, swing

I have a box panel with two different components in it, the panel requires for the window to have a lot of empty space at the bottom before drawing itself.

```
val boxPanel = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
    val widthMax = math.max(panel1.maximumSize.width, panel2.maximumSize.width)
    val heightMax = panel1.maximumSize.height + panel2.maximumSize.height

    contents += panel1
    contents += panel2

    maximumSize = new Dimension(widthMax, heightMax)
    preferredSize = new Dimension(widthMax, heightMax)
}
```

[image: Alignment issues happening]

On the left the window is really big, on the right I've made it small enough for panel2 to draw over panel1.
I would like to have the panel "see" that it can infact make itself bigger. How can I do that?